Why isn't the `pytest_addoption` hook run with the configured `testpaths`? (usage error)
Summary:
I'm trying to set up a custom pytest option with the pytest_addoption feature.
But when trying to configure my project with a project.toml file while using the said custom option, I'm getting the following error:
$ pytest --foo foo
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --foo
  inifile: /home/vmonteco/Code/MREs/pytest__addoption__pyproject_toml/01_adding_pyproject.toml/pyproject.toml
  rootdir: /home/vmonteco/Code/MREs/pytest__addoption__pyproject_toml/01_adding_pyproject.toml

Why is this problem occurring despite the configured test path and how could I solve it?
Used versions are:

Python 3.10.13
Pytest 8.1.1


How to reproduce:
Step 1 - before organizing the project, it works:
I start with a very simple test in a single directory.
$ tree
.
├── conftest.py
└── test_foo.py

1 directory, 2 files
$ 


conftest.py:

import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--foo", action="store")

@pytest.fixture
def my_val(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--foo")


test_foo.py:

def test_foo(my_val):
    assert my_val == "foo"

$ pytest --foo bar
=============================== test session starts ===============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.13, pytest-8.1.1, pluggy-1.5.0
rootdir: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/pytest__addoption__pyproject_toml/00_simplest_case
collected 1 item                                                                  

test_foo.py F                                                               [100%]

==================================== FAILURES =====================================
____________________________________ test_foo _____________________________________

my_val = 'bar'

    def test_foo(my_val):
>       assert my_val == "foo"
E       AssertionError: assert 'bar' == 'foo'
E         
E         - foo
E         + bar

test_foo.py:2: AssertionError
============================= short test summary info =============================
FAILED test_foo.py::test_foo - AssertionError: assert 'bar' == 'foo'
================================ 1 failed in 0.01s ================================
$ 

Step 2 - When adding an empty pyproject.toml and reorganizing the project, it fails:
$ tree
.
├── my_project
│   └── my_tests
│       ├── conftest.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_foo.py
└── pyproject.toml

3 directories, 4 files
$ pytest --foo bar
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --foo
  inifile: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/pytest__addoption__pyproject_toml/01_adding_pyproject_toml/pyproject.toml
  rootdir: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/pytest__addoption__pyproject_toml/01_adding_pyproject_toml

$ 

Notes:

In doubt, I also added an __init__.py file.
The pyproject.toml seems to be recognized despite not having the required [tool.pytest.ini_options] table, thus apparently contradicting the documentation.

However, there's a simple workaround that seems to work in this specific case:
Just manually passing the test path to my tests as command line argument seems enough to make things work correctly again:
$ pytest --foo bar my_project/my_tests
=============================== test session starts ===============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.13, pytest-8.1.1, pluggy-1.5.0
rootdir: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/pytest__addoption__pyproject_toml/01_adding_pyproject_toml
configfile: pyproject.toml
collected 1 item                                                                  

my_project/my_tests/test_foo.py F                                           [100%]

==================================== FAILURES =====================================
____________________________________ test_foo _____________________________________

my_val = 'bar'

    def test_foo(my_val):
>       assert my_val == "foo"
E       AssertionError: assert 'bar' == 'foo'
E         
E         - foo
E         + bar

my_project/my_tests/test_foo.py:2: AssertionError
============================= short test summary info =============================
FAILED my_project/my_tests/test_foo.py::test_foo - AssertionError: assert 'bar' == 'foo'
================================ 1 failed in 0.02s ================================
$

But I'd like to avoid that and I'd rather have my project correctly configured.
Step 3 - Unsuccessfully trying to configure testpaths in the pyproject.toml.
The best explanation I found so far relies on the following points from the documentation:

The necessity to put pytest_addoption in an "initial" conftest.py:

This hook is only called for initial conftests.

pytest_addoption documentation


What is actually an "initial conftest.py":
Initial conftest are for each test path the files whose path match <test_path>/conftest.py or <test_test>/test*/conftest.py.


by loading all “initial “conftest.py files:


determine the test paths: specified on the command line, otherwise in testpaths if defined and running from the rootdir, otherwise the current dir
for each test path, load conftest.py and test*/conftest.py relative to the directory part of the test path, if exist. Before a conftest.py file is loaded, load conftest.py files in all of its parent directories. After a conftest.py file is loaded, recursively load all plugins specified in its pytest_plugins variable if present.


Plugin discovery order at tool startup



So, if I understand well:

my error seems to occurs because if I don't provide an explicit test path, the current directory is used. But in that case, my conftest.py is too deep into the arborescence to be used as an initial conftest.

With my workaround, explicitly passing a deeper test path solves this by making the conftest "initial" again.


From this, it would seem appropriate to try to translate my command line argument path into a bit of configuration (testpaths) as shown in the relevant documentation.
But when trying to run my command again, I still get the same error:
$ cat pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
testpaths = [
          "my_project/my_tests",
]
$ tree
.
├── my_project
│   └── my_tests
│       ├── conftest.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_foo.py
└── pyproject.toml

3 directories, 4 files
$ pytest --foo bar                  
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --foo
  inifile: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/pytest__addoption__pyproject_toml/02_attempt_to_solve/pyproject.toml
  rootdir: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/pytest__addoption__pyproject_toml/02_attempt_to_solve

$ 

I also tried to use a different kind of configuration file:
$ cat pytest.ini  
[pytest]
testpaths = my_project/my_tests
$ pytest --foo bar
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --foo
  inifile: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/pytest__addoption__pyproject_toml/03_with_pytest_ini/pytest.ini
  rootdir: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/pytest__addoption__pyproject_toml/03_with_pytest_ini

$ 

But it still doesn't solve the problem despite the equivalent as command line argument seems to work. Why?

Addendum - raw output of new step 2 reproduction session:
Script started on 2024-08-06 03:23:13+02:00 [TERM="tmux-256color" TTY="/dev/pts/8" COLUMNS="126" LINES="69"]
[1m[7m%[27m[1m[0m                                                                                                                             
 
k..ew_pytest_MRE\]7;file://vmonteco-desktop/home/vmonteco/code/MREs/new_pytest_MRE\
[0m[27m[24m[J[01;32m➜  [36mnew_pytest_MRE[00m [K[?1h=[?2004httree[?1l>[?2004l
 
 
ktree\[01;34m.[0m
├── [01;34mmy_project[0m
│   └── [01;34mmy_tests[0m
│       ├── conftest.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_foo.py
└── pyproject.toml
 
3 directories, 4 files
[1m[7m%[27m[1m[0m                                                                                                                             
 
k..ew_pytest_MRE\]7;file://vmonteco-desktop/home/vmonteco/code/MREs/new_pytest_MRE\
[0m[27m[24m[J[01;32m➜  [36mnew_pytest_MRE[00m [K[?1h=[?2004hccat pyproject.toml[1m [0m[0m [?1l>[?2004l
 
 
kcat\[1m[7m%[27m[1m[0m                                                                                                                             
 
k..ew_pytest_MRE\]7;file://vmonteco-desktop/home/vmonteco/code/MREs/new_pytest_MRE\
[0m[27m[24m[J[01;32m➜  [36mnew_pytest_MRE[00m [K[?1h=[?2004hccat my_project[1m/[0m[0m/my_tests[1m/[0m[0m/conftest.py[1m [0m[0m [?1l>[?2004l
 
 
kcat\import pytest
 
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--foo", action="store")
 
@pytest.fixture
def my_val(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--foo")
[1m[7m%[27m[1m[0m                                                                                                                             
 
k..ew_pytest_MRE\]7;file://vmonteco-desktop/home/vmonteco/code/MREs/new_pytest_MRE\
[0m[27m[24m[J[01;32m➜  [36mnew_pytest_MRE[00m [K[?1h=[?2004hcat my_project/my_tests/conftest.py           __init__.py[1m [0m[0m [?1l>[?2004l
 
 
kcat\[1m[7m%[27m[1m[0m                                                                                                                             
 
k..ew_pytest_MRE\]7;file://vmonteco-desktop/home/vmonteco/code/MREs/new_pytest_MRE\
[0m[27m[24m[J[01;32m➜  [36mnew_pytest_MRE[00m [K[?1h=[?2004hcat my_project/my_tests/__init__.py           test_foo.py[1m [0m[0m [?1l>[?2004l
 
 
kcat\def test_foo(my_val):
    assert my_val == "foo"
[1m[7m%[27m[1m[0m                                                                                                                             
 
k..ew_pytest_MRE\]7;file://vmonteco-desktop/home/vmonteco/code/MREs/new_pytest_MRE\
[0m[27m[24m[J[01;32m➜  [36mnew_pytest_MRE[00m [K[?1h=[?2004hppython --version[?1l>[?2004l
 
 
kpython\Python 3.10.13
[1m[7m%[27m[1m[0m                                                                                                                             
 
k..ew_pytest_MRE\]7;file://vmonteco-desktop/home/vmonteco/code/MREs/new_pytest_MRE\
[0m[27m[24m[J[01;32m➜  [36mnew_pytest_MRE[00m [K[?1h=[?2004hpython --version            est --version[?1l>[?2004l
 
 
kpytest\pytest 8.1.1
[1m[7m%[27m[1m[0m                                                                                                                             
 
k..ew_pytest_MRE\]7;file://vmonteco-desktop/home/vmonteco/code/MREs/new_pytest_MRE\
[0m[27m[24m[J[01;32m➜  [36mnew_pytest_MRE[00m [K[?1h=[?2004hppytest -fo  -foo bar[?1l>[?2004l
 
 
kpytest\[31mERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --foo
  inifile: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/new_pytest_MRE/pyproject.toml
  rootdir: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/new_pytest_MRE
[0m
[1m[7m%[27m[1m[0m                                                                                                                             
 
k..ew_pytest_MRE\]7;file://vmonteco-desktop/home/vmonteco/code/MREs/new_pytest_MRE\
[0m[27m[24m[J[01;31m➜  [36mnew_pytest_MRE[00m [K[?1h=[?2004h[?2004l
 
 
 

    Script done on 2024-08-06 03:24:49+02:00 [COMMAND_EXIT_CODE="4"]

link to pastebin

@wim Thank you. I retried a new reproduction of the step 2 from scratch and I can confirm I reproduced again. I added the raw output I got with the script command to remove any ambiguity. I haven't found a way to format it a better way yet but I'll retry tomorrow.

Okay I can reproduce it in a container now, not sure why I couldn't reproduce it on my host directly earlier. I retract my vote. Before I worry about the cause, is there a reason you don't want to just put the pytest_addoption hooks into a top-level ("initial") conftest.py file? That seems to make the most sense?

This looks like a similar Q&A pytest_sessionstart in conftest.py not running when conftest.py isn't in main testing directory, and this looks related on their issue tracker https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/10988

@wim The answers to the linked post indeed give a similar and consistant analysis with what I mentionned. However despite that understanding either my conftest is still not "initial" or my "testpaths" isn't correctly configured and the problem persists but I'm unsure about how to debug that.
The GH issue also is similar but this fix was merged in an anterior version. I'll consider filling an issue as well.

That's the same conclusion I came to.. your analysis looks correct and it seams like there is still some bugs lurking here in pytest itself. Or at least, the docs needs changing to reflect the real behavior.

@wim About your previous question I'm trying to build a pytest-based testing tool that could itself have unit tests. So there could be two different test suites. Hence the non-root conftest.
Thank you for your help. I think I'll file a bug report.

I filed a bug report which can now be found here:
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/12696
I also reproduced it with pytest 8.3.2.

@wim God, I found out what was going on and now I feel stupid: the explanation was way simpler than that.

Oh, wow. I didn't know this restriction either. I was just assuming pytest would be equivalent to argparse where --foo=foo and --foo foo are the same.

It looks like it indeed was an usage error (and also facepalm-worthy material):
pytest --foo=bar rather than pytest --foo bar.
$ pytest --foo bar
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --foo
  inifile: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/pytest__addoption__pyproject_toml/02_attempt_to_solve/pyproject.toml
  rootdir: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/pytest__addoption__pyproject_toml/02_attempt_to_solve

$ pytest --foo=bar
=============================== test session starts ===============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.13, pytest-8.3.2, pluggy-1.5.0
rootdir: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/pytest__addoption__pyproject_toml/02_attempt_to_solve
configfile: pyproject.toml
testpaths: my_project/my_tests
collected 1 item                                                                  

my_project/my_tests/test_foo.py F                                           [100%]

==================================== FAILURES =====================================
____________________________________ test_foo _____________________________________

my_val = 'bar'

    def test_foo(my_val):
>       assert my_val == "foo"
E       AssertionError: assert 'bar' == 'foo'
E         
E         - foo
E         + bar

my_project/my_tests/test_foo.py:2: AssertionError
============================= short test summary info =============================
FAILED my_project/my_tests/test_foo.py::test_foo - AssertionError: assert 'bar' == 'foo'
================================ 1 failed in 0.02s ================================
$ 


Addendum:
Here's on explanation on why pytest is designed like thas.
